# Wrong encoding at runtime in one of the modules of an Android project

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

Two of my colleagues at work have a strange issue that I never encountered before and I can't figure out how to solve.

We have an Android project with 3 modules. The main one is app, it depends on data module and this one depends on core module. Now inside the core module, we have a class that has some hardcoded Strings using non-Ascii characters. Inside IDE everything is displayed correctly (picture 1), the file is opened with UTF-8 encoding as it should and as set in settings (picture 2). However once I run this app, the encoding at runtime for these strings change to ANSI (picture 1). For example I have a letter "ł" which in hex is "c5 82", but at runtime it is split to 1 byte each with ANSI encoding, which results in c5=Å and 82=‚ as you can notice also on the pictures. http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

There are 2 weird things about it:

1) I have the same laptop model with the same Windows installed and I have no issues with it

2) Even weirder (picture 3), when I will make a copy of this class and move it to other modules like app or data, the encoding suddenly is perfect at runtime.

Because of the 2nd point above I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong. If it was a system issue or java JRE or JDK issue, it should be affecting all the files, no matter the project or module, but here it's not the case as everything is perfect if I move the file to other module. It's also not a project issue, as I don't have the same problem as they do and I also have Windows machine (same OS version).

I've reinstalled the Android Studio from scratch, deleting all the caches/previous settings and cloned the repo again... no help.

Windows 10, using Android Studio 2.3.2

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please check the encoding at the right bottom of android studio

Comment: That's not it Jiang. In IDE everything is fine (and it is set to UTF-8 btw). The problem is at runtime (or during compilation, either way). Also, as mentioned before, if it was a project issue (as it would have to be the case if the encoding for the file was wrong) then it would be observer by me as well, but it's not.

Comment: the `runtime` you mean is the IDE's watch window? I think the only way to check the runtime character value is to print it whith `String.codePointAt()`, but not watch in any String view.

Comment: I mean that if I run this code on the device or emulator the characters are messed up (i.e. the ANSI encoding is used for these strings instead of UTF-8).

Comment: Well, can you make a logcat to print char code by `String.codePointAt()`? to make sure there IS problem in runtime string first.

Comment: Sure. On my machine, when I run it I get:
App: 322, Data: 322, Core: 322

On my colleagues machine:
App: 322, Data: 322, Core: 197

As you can see, the character from the Core module is the one that is broken as I explained in the topic.